# Can I use a prepaid travel card (loaded with South African Rand) to purchase attraction tickets online?

Tags: payment-cards, south-africa

I am travelling to South Africa this year and want to buy some attraction tickets beforehand. Can I do this with a prepaid travel card, which is loaded with South African Rand?

The attraction website allows you to pay by international PayPal or credit card. Would it allow me to use the prepaid card as it is loaded with the correct currency and treated as a MasterCard?

Comment: Welcome to the site, those are really two different questions you're asking, the first also seems off-topic. The second might be answerable but I'd suggest editing and narrowing down your scope a little

Comment: @blackbird57 My first question is the main question. I want to purchase attraction tickets from a South African website but I am not sure if I can use a pre-paid card to do this. Are they considered the same as a credit card due to it being a mastercard?  I don't really want to get a credit card unless I have to. With regards to off topic, as I am a new member it wouldn't let me create my own tags.

Comment: Only one sure way to find, try and then report the outcome here.

Comment: In general, if it has the Mastercard logo on it, then you should be able to ise it as a mastercard

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're referring to "MasterCard Everyday Prepaid Cards".

From [MasterCard's official website](https://www.mastercard.com/mel/personal/en/aboutourcards/prepaid/faqs.html#q04):

> You can use your MasterCard Everyday Prepaid Card **anywhere Debit
>   MasterCard cards are accepted**—that's millions of locations worldwide
>   from retail stores to online, mail, and phone orders. You can also use
>   your card to pay bills online.

So, as long as an establishment accepts MasterCard debit cards, it will also accept "MasterCard Everyday Prepaid Cards".

While the source doesn't say it explicitly, the specific mention of "debit cards" may suggest that some establishments may only accept credit cards (and not debit cards.) The implication seems to be that these establishments (if they exist) may not support prepaid cards either. That's something I would check with each establishment.

However, I very much doubt that this would be a problem. These days, almost anyone who accepts credit cards accepts debit cards too. Also:

[Credit cards and cash](http://www.southafrica.info/travel/advice/currency.htm#.V-Pwf8vhXqA#ixzz4KzrWQri1):

> **All major credit cards can be used in South Africa**, with American
>   Express and Diners Club enjoying less universal acceptance than
>   **MasterCard** and Visa. If you have a so-called "chip card", you will be
>   required to enter a pin code. Pin-based debit cards are often accepted
>   too. Remember to notify your bank in advance that you will be
>   travelling.

According to the first source, the "MasterCard Everyday Prepaid Cards" **will play exactly like normal MasterCard debit cards.**

<sup>The emphasis is mine in both quotes.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

For a MasterCard (or Visa, or AmEx, etc.) branded card, so long as there are sufficient funds in the account when the authorization is done, yes.  It behaves just like any other Credit or Debit card.

Also, the currency in the account is not so much an issue.  The hold and settlement will be done at the prevailing rate.